# Select item based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database...

```
descriptionID   | ItemID  |  description 
--------------------------------------------  
1               |   1     |    Blue
2               |   1     |    Small
3               |   1     |    Circular
4               |   2     |    Blue
5               |   2     |    Large
6               |   3     |    Small
7               |   4     |    Blue
...                 ...           ...
```

I want to return itemID where it has entries blue and small therefore returning itemID = 1 and no other itemID.

```
ItemID
--------------
   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT itemId FROM tbl t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE description = 'Blue' AND itemId = t1.itemId)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE description = 'Small' AND itemId = t1.ItemId)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation.  Assuming no duplciates:

```
select itemid
from t
where description in ('Blue', 'Small')
group by itemid
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it as you say it.

Items with `Blue` description and (set intersect) items with `Small` description

```
select itemId from tab where description = 'Blue'
INTERSECT
select itemId from tab where description = 'Small';
```